# Search box to show information in line chart

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, chart.js

I'm trying to add a search box in to my web page that allows the user to select the data to show in a line chart.

I know how to pass the variable from the search box to PHP but the question is how can I render the chart in Javascript to update the information with the value of the search box after I have updated it in the PHP?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost/chartjs/followersdata.php",
    type: "GET",
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);

      var userid = [];
      var facebook_follower = [];
      var twitter_follower = [];
      var googleplus_follower = [];

      for (var i in data) {
        userid.push("UserID " + data[i].userid);
        facebook_follower.push(data[i].facebook);
        twitter_follower.push(data[i].twitter);
        googleplus_follower.push(data[i].googleplus);
      }

      var chartdata = {
        labels: userid,
        datasets: [{
            label: "facebook",
            fill: false,
            lineTension: 0.1,
            backgroundColor: "rgba(59, 89, 152, 0.75)",
            borderColor: "rgba(59, 89, 152, 1)",
            pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(59, 89, 152, 1)",
            pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(59, 89, 152, 1)",
            data: facebook_follower
          },
          {
            label: "twitter",
            fill: false,
            lineTension: 0.1,
            backgroundColor: "rgba(29, 202, 255, 0.75)",
            borderColor: "rgba(29, 202, 255, 1)",
            pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(29, 202, 255, 1)",
            pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(29, 202, 255, 1)",
            data: twitter_follower
          },
          {
            label: "googleplus",
            fill: false,
            lineTension: 0.1,
            backgroundColor: "rgba(211, 72, 54, 0.75)",
            borderColor: "rgba(211, 72, 54, 1)",
            pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(211, 72, 54, 1)",
            pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(211, 72, 54, 1)",
            data: googleplus_follower
          }
        ]
      };

      var ctx = $("#mycanvas");

      var LineGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: chartdata
      });
    },
    error: function(data) {}
  });
});
```

Thanks for your replies.

Answer (score 0):

This link can help you
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/api.html

```
// duration is the time for the animation of the redraw in milliseconds
// lazy is a boolean. if true, the animation can be interrupted by other animations
LineGraph.render({
    duration: 800,
    lazy: false,
    easing: 'easeOutBounce'
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Maybe I didn't explain my problem well.I have a form to submit data into a php to retrieve data from mysql database. I have manage to do that but when I click in the submit button I can't render the chart, I only received the json with all the data filtered by the submit text.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to do this, but I only return the json not the chart rendered.

```
<form action="./followersdata.php" method="post">
    Licencia:<br>
    <input type="text" name="licencia" id="licencia"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onsubmit="return showgraph();">
</form>
```